# D3.js - browser freezing - too many elements on updating with time?

Tags: d3.js

I have some problems with my "fooling around D3.js code".

I created a number of round circles and put time in them to be updated every second, this does however soon lead to the different browsers crashing or freezing.

From some googleing I'd assume that my problem is that there are too many elements after a while, but I didn't figure out how to update it without this problem occurring.

The problematic part of the code:

```
    oranges.append("circle")
        .attr("cx", function (d) {return d*2;})
        .attr("cy", function (d) {return d*2;})
        .attr("r", function (d) {return d/2;})
        .attr("fill", "orange")
        .attr("stroke", "red")
        .attr("stroke-width", "4px")



var timeoranges = oranges.append("text")
        .attr("x", function (d) {return d*2 - 15;})
        .attr("y", function (d) {return d*2;})
        .attr("dy", ".35em");

function updateOranges() {  


timeoranges.text(function() { 
        setTimeout(updateOranges, 1000);
        return Date();});
}
updateOranges();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you are passing to `timeoranges.text` will be called for **every element** in the `timeoranges` selection.  So if you have a 100 circles you are calling `setTimeout` 100 times, which in turn calls `setTimeout` 100 times, etc...

I think what you mean to do is:

```
function updateOranges() {  
  timeoranges.text(function() {        
        return Date();
  });
  setTimeout(updateOranges, 1000);
}
updateOranges();
```

Comment: Now it seems to be working.
Thanks for the explanation! :)